# How to look at next added value? Google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

[image][image]I am trying to combine sheets 1 and 2 to become sheet 3 and I would like the bottom row on sheet 3 to be the next inputted value from sheets 1 or 2. for example if row 11 is added into sheet 1 I would like that to be row 15 in sheet 3. Please see attached images.

I also have the following code:

```
 [![function combineSheets() {
    var sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s1= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var s2= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var s3= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  
  var s1values = s1.getRange(1,1,s1.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  var s2values = s2.getRange(1,1,s2.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
 
  s3values =  s1values.concat(s2values);
  s3.getRange(1,1,s3values.length,3).setValues(s3values);
}][1]][1]
```

enter image description here

Comment: How the values are added in sheets 1 and 2? Is the order of the values in sheet 3 important or can the values of both sheets be concatenated as in the example?

Comment: Your function `combineSheets()` woks fine as far as I can tell. What do you want? Do you want to be able to update the Sheets1 and Sheet2 interactively? Or you want to copy all rows from Sheet2 without its first row? You can do it if you change the range to `var s2values = s2.getRange(2,1,s2.getLastRow(),3).getValues();` `2,1,...` instead of `1,1,...`

Comment: Sheet 1 and 2 both have manual input from another user and I would like sheet 3 to show both data sets combined- with the next available row in sheet 3 updating to show the next user input either on sheet 1 or sheet 2

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*Use [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)*. Check [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en):

> You can join multiple ranges into one continuous range using this same punctuation. For example, to combine values from `A1-A10` with the values from `D1-D10`, you can use the following formula to create a range in a continuous column: `={A1:A10; D1:D10}`

### Formula

`=query({Sheet1!A:C;Sheet2!A:C},"Select * where Col1 is not null")`

### Update

To add the new values below you have to sort the range. You can do this easily with the [sort](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)) method. Also, on the second sheet I would not take the first row as you would get the header twice.

### Code

```
function combineSheets() {
  var sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2 = sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var s3 = sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  var s1values = s1.getRange(1, 1, s1.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
  var s2values = s2.getRange(1, 1, s2.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();

  s3values = s1values.concat(s2values);
  s3.getRange(1, 1, s3values.length, 3).setValues(s3values).sort(1)
}
```

### Considerations

Finally, you must keep in mind what will be the method of use. In this case, being a function without trigger, it is only executed when `run` is pressed. You can add a button to any page (or all three) that is in charge of calling the function. Or you can also use a trigger that detects an edit in any cell and calls the function. The best way to do this depends on your scenario and your needs.

Comment: Hi how would this be written in google app scripts? Thank you

Comment: Yes, but I think it has no advantage and would be quite a messy thing to do. You could use a trigger `onEdit` so that every time a new value is entered in either of the last two rows of sheet1 or sheet2, a new one is also entered in sheet3 that refers to the manually entered row. For example `[=Sheet2!A1, =Sheet2!B1, =Sheet2!C1]`. In this way you could update the values in sheets 1 and 2 and the changes would be reflected in 3. But if the important thing is to maintain order, it would be best to sort sheet3 and keep the initial formula in `A1`.

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
      var sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s1= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var s3= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  
  var s1values = s1.getRange(1,1,s1.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  var s2values = s2.getRange(1,1,s2.getLastRow(),3).getValues();

  s3values =  s1values.concat(s2values);
  s3.getRange(1,1,s3values.length,3).setValues(s3values);
}  This doesn't seem to add the new edited value at the bottom- it adds sheet 1 in above and pushes the values for sheet 2 down?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if it now meets your needs.